# Chckpoint Remote Access VPN Multiple ISP external interface

Tags: vpn, ipsec, checkpoint

I'm in a situation where I have to suggest the best solution when client has two ISP connected to a checkpoint firewall cluster. AFAIK, we cannot activate or make use of two external interfaces for Remote access vpn; this is something we manually activate based our needs. 
Does anyone know an alternative way to make use of two ISPs?

Thanks in advance
AN